# Remote Registry fails to mount on WSO2 ESB 4.5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to mount remote registry on to ESB 4.5.0 as advised here: http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2012/09/create-jdbc-mount-to-wso2-governance.html

Everything is done according to given instructions - however I'm getting the follwoing errors during ESB start up:

```
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-10-18 07:48:42,555]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor} -  The instance     identifier was not specified for the mount: /_system/config {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor}

TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-10-18 07:48:42,557]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor} -  The instance identifier was not specified for the mount: /_system/governance {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor}
```

with no more additional errors.

ESB registry.xml code snippet:

```
<dbconfig name="wso2registry_mounted">
    <datasource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB_GREG</datasource>
</dbconfig>

<remoteinstance url="https://localhost:9445/registry">
    <id>wso2_registry_mounted</id>
    <dbconfig>wso2registry_mounted</dbconfig>
    <readonly>false</readonly>
    <enablecache>true</enablecache>
    <registryroot>/</registryroot>
</remoteinstance>

<mount overwrite="true" path="/_system/config">
    <instanceid>wso2_registry_mounted</instanceid>
    <targetpath>/_system/nodes</targetpath>
</mount>

<mount overwrite="true" path="/_system/governance">
    <instanceid>wso2_registry_mounted</instanceid>
    <targetpath>/_system/governance</targetpath>
</mount>
```

Could someone advise what's wrong here?

Best Regards,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `<instanceId>` not `<instanceid>` in the configuration. There are similar camel case problems. Please have a look at this configuration elements.

```
<remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9447/registry">
        <id>instanceid</id>
        <dbConfig>govRegistry</dbConfig>
        <readOnly>true</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
    </remoteInstance>

    <mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>instanceid</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/esb</targetPath>
    </mount>

    <mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>instanceid</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
    </mount>
```